# Summing all 5 table values to form new table?

Tags: mysql

I have 5 tables with following properties,

```
+--------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field              | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| actor_id           | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| activity_object_id | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| interest_level     | tinyint(4)  | YES  |     | 10      |       |
| feed_view          | smallint(6) | YES  |     | 0       |       |
| quick_view         | smallint(6) | YES  |     | 0       |       |
| page_view          | smallint(6) | YES  |     | 0       |       |
| fullscreen_view    | smallint(6) | YES  |     | 0       |       |
| reserved1          | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| reserved2          | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| reserved3          | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| created_at         | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| updated_at         | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

How we can create new temporary table which is sum of all the 5 table values. **activity_object_id** is unique and one table might contain activity_object_id while the other one may not.

table1 has one active_object_id say 'gowthamkey', table2 has same key 'gowthamkey', and table3 might not have 'gowthamkey'. So I want to sum up all the tables values into new table, so that it has one key 'gowthamkey' where values are sum of:

feed_view,quick_view,page_view,fullscreen_view,reserved1,reserved2,reserved3 **except** actor_id, interest_level, created_at, updated_at.

Here is my query as per @bummer answer:

```
CREATE TABLE actor_activity_object_stats_temp_7_days_12 AS 
select actor_id, activity_object_id, interest_level, SUM(feed_view) AS feed_view, SUM(quick_view) AS quick_view, SUM(fullscreen_view) as fullscreen_view 
from (
    select * from actor_activity_object_stats_temp_2016_04_29 
    union all, 
    select * from actor_activity_object_stats_temp_2016_04_30 
    union all, 
    select * from actor_activity_object_stats_temp_2016_05_01 
    union all, 
    select * from actor_activity_object_stats_temp_2016_05_02 
    union all, 
    select * from actor_activity_object_stats_temp_2016_05_03 
    union all, 
    select * from actor_activity_object_stats_temp_2016_05_04 
    union all, 
    select * from actor_activity_object_stats_temp_2016_05_05 
    union all, 
    select * from actor_activity_object_stats_temp_2016_05_06 
    union all, 
    select * from actor_activity_object_stats_temp_2016_05_07 
    union all, 
    select * from actor_activity_object_stats_temp_2016_05_08 ) AS X
group by activity_object_id
```

Comment: why do you have five tables if they are all the same??

Comment: Daily generated tables based on few stats. Now we want weekly stats based on all these daily based stats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with a `UNION`, then use `SUM()` to add all the values from all the tables for the same `activity_object_id`.

```
CREATE TABLE new_table
AS SELECT activity_object_id, SUM(feed_view) AS feed_view, SUM(quick_view) AS quick_view, ...
    FROM (SELECT * FROM table1
          UNION ALL
          SELECT * FROM table2
          UNION ALL
          SELECT * FROM table3
          ...) AS x
    GROUP BY activity_object_id
```

Comment: @bammer, got syntax error near select * FROM table1

Comment: @bammer, just found that. Thanks. :)

Comment: My name isn't bummer or bammer.

Comment: I apologise for that, sorry. I didn't notice that. Sorry @Barmar.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should solve your issue.

```
create table new_table
as
select * from table1
union
select * from table2
union
select * from table3
union
select * from table4
union
select * from table5)
```

here's a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6473b9/1/0) to illustrate.

Comment: On what basis, it will take the unique value (active_objective_id). It is not working. It is producing table having duplicate values (name - rocky - in my case active_object_id which should be unique) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/56f52c/1

Comment: what do you mean it should be unique? what i understood from your question was that each table has a unique `active_objective_id` already. so it's just about merging the tables. are you saying that each table might have similar `active_objective_id`s?

Comment: No, may be mistake. It is same across all the tables. But table 1 has one active_object_id say 'gowthamkey', table 2 has same key 'gowthamkey', and table 3 might not have 'gowthamkey'. So I want to sum up all the tables values into new table, so that it has one key 'gowthamkey' where values are sum of feed_view,quick_view,page_view,fullscreen_view,reserved1,reserved2,reserved3,.

Comment: ok that explains for the `int` properties. what do you want to do with dates?